# Output Limitations in ColdFusion 9?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have my code setup to send me emails every time someone is filling up a form but the email reports are being cut off.

This is what I have in my database as an input example from a user:

```
awd wda aawd awd awd aaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd 
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awd
```

And this is what shows up in the email report:

```
awd wda aawd awd awd aaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd
awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd awd awdaawd
```

I don't have any styling in my email template other than the regular

tags to separate the answer output.

Is there any limitation on what you can output?

This is my CF code:

```
 <cfquery name="fullResults" datasource="#variables.dsn#">
     select s.id, s.name surveyname, q.question, subq.answer subquestion, isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(a.answer, r.textboxmulti),r.other),r.textbox),r.truefalse) as         selectedanswer, a.*, r.*
    from results r
    join questions q on r.questionidfk = q.id
    left join answers subq on r.itemidfk = subq.id
    left join answers a on r.answeridfk = a.id
    join surveys s on q.surveyidfk = s.id
    where owneridfk = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.ownerid#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" maxlength="255">
    order by s.id, owneridfk, q.rank, subq.rank desc
   </cfquery>


#fullResults.selectedanswer#
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does Len( isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(a.answer, r.textboxmulti),r.other),r.textbox),r.truefalse) ) return?

Comment: it goes through those columns and grabs their value. For example you can get something like "comment","comment 2","another comment","Yes"

Comment: I thought that might have been the problem... one of the fields being smaller in length than the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that in`isnull(isnull(isnull(isnull(a.answer, r.textboxmulti),r.other),r.textbox),r.truefalse) as selectedanswer` the `a.answer` was set to 225 character and everything else was trimmed down to that. After I added a convert function around it everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should check your Data Source setup in the ColdFusion Administrator and make sure that the Long Text Buffer is set to a long enough value to allow you to pull out the data you need.
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this does not solve the issue. I set it up to 640 000 000 chars and still getting the same output.